# Concatenate Subqueries with Unions (one table with two condition)

Tags: sql, join, subquery, conditional-statements, union

I have 1 table with 2 different conditions.
I want to present AR, annual, AR / annual * 365.

the code below can run

```
select AR, AR*365 
from (select sum(total_amount) AR
from invoices
where issue_date is not null and closed_at is null
and issue_date <= 'January 1,2020' and issue_date <DATEADD (DAY, 1, 'December 31,2020') 
UNION
select sum(total_amount)
from invoices
where closed_at <= 'January 1,2020' and closed_at <DATEADD (DAY, 1, 'December 31,2020')
)x group by AR;
```

the result :

```
   AR
1,895.23            15,903,040.94
691,758.95          5,804,609,943.1
```

and then i want to display AR, annual, AR/annual*365 but get error :

```
select AR, annual, AR/annual*365 from
(select sum(total_amount) AR
from invoices
where issue_date is not null and closed_at is null
and issue_date <= 'January 1,2020' and issue_date <DATEADD (DAY, 1, 'December 31,2020')
UNION
select sum(total_amount) annual
from invoices
where closed_at <= 'January 1,2020' and closed_at <DATEADD (DAY, 1, 'December 31,2020'))x group by         
AR;
```

When you want to display the annual value of "annual" the first line/first select cannot be read ...

but annual can be read when "annual" from the first line we delete.

I want the "annual" from the first line / first select to be read so that it can be calculated with other values.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: I think you want to `cross join` these two results rather than `union`. That way you can access both values at once. Bu aside from that, other issues you have are: `union` will distinct-ify and remove identical results, you want `union all`. The date filters don't make sense, did you mean `>= and <`. No need to `group by AR` in your outer query as they will be just two different values anyway. Specify date literals like this `'20201231'`

Comment: Thankyou @GordonLinoff

Comment: Thankyou @Charlieface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select AR, annual, AR/annual*365 from
(select sum(case when issue_date is not null and closed_at is null
                  and issue_date <= 'January 1,2020' 
                  and issue_date <DATEADD (DAY, 1, 'December 31,2020') 
                 then total_amount end) AR,
        sum(case when closed_at <= 'January 1,2020' 
                  and closed_at <DATEADD (DAY, 1, 'December 31,2020') 
                 then total_amount end) as annual
   from invoices) t
```

It is possible that `annual` is 0 and it is used in division so use the appropriate logic there.

Comment: Thankyou @Popeye

Comment: You can consider accepting this answer if it resolved your iasue.

Comment: Hi bro, can you help me, I have a case about date and time. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712954/how-to-read-from-the-two-same-dates-without-input-the-time