# How to read from the two same dates without input the time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, time

I have a query like below.

```
SELECT
occupation AS 'Contact occupation',
sum(total) AS 'Quantity'
FROM
(
SELECT
CASE
WHEN contacts.occupation IS NULL THEN 'Other'
WHEN trim(contacts.occupation) = '' THEN 'Other'
ELSE contacts.occupation
END AS occupation, count(DISTINCT(concat(patients.id, '-', individual_appointments.practitioner_id))) AS total
FROM
individual_appointments
JOIN patients ON
patients.id = individual_appointments.patient_id
JOIN practitioners ON
practitioners.id = individual_appointments.practitioner_id
JOIN businesses ON
businesses.id = individual_appointments.business_id
JOIN referral_sources ON
referral_sources.patient_id = individual_appointments.patient_id
JOIN referral_source_types ON
referral_source_types.id = referral_sources.referral_source_type_id
LEFT JOIN contacts ON
referral_sources.referring_contact_id = contacts.id
WHERE
patients.created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-22' AND '2018-05-22'
AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), referral_source_types.name) = 'Contact' [[
AND {{practitioner}}]] [[
AND {{clinic}}]]
AND isnull(individual_appointments.cancelled_at, '') = ''
AND individual_appointments.did_not_arrive <> 1
GROUP BY
contacts.occupation ) marketing_referrers
GROUP BY
occupation,
marketing_referrers.total
ORDER BY
total DESC;
```

When I submit a date like the following `patients.created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-22' AND '2018-05-22'` it doesn't return anything but if I enter `BETWEEN '2018-05-22' patients.created_at 'AND' 2018-05-23'` it returns a value.

I think if I just input two of the same date without entering the time then the time will be `00:00:00 - 00:00:00`.

How to read `00:00:00 - 23:59:59` when we input two of the same date without entering the time?

The date format in the table is filled as follows `"Thursday, August 20, 2020, 9:49 AM"` but it can be read if we just input the date, for example `2020-08-20`.

Your help means a lot to me, thank you

Comment: Why oh why won't you indent anything???

Comment: Use `patients.created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-22 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-22 23:59:59'`. If `fsp` of the column is set then add according decimal part to the upper limit, for example, `'2018-05-22 23:59:59.999'`.

Comment: `The date format in the table is filled as follows "Thursday, August 20, 2020, 9:49 AM"` I don't understand this statement;at least, I hope that I don't)

Comment: @Strawberry sorry i mean "Thursday, August 20, 2020, 9:49 AM" is data values in table. Data type is datetime

Comment: @Akina is there any other way if we input the two same dates without the time? Like two same date but can read 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 without needing to input the time?

Comment: This depends on data datatype, not on parameters value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data type is `datetime` then  you can add:

```
WHERE patients.createdAt >= '2018-05-22' and patients.createdAt < '2018-05-23'
```

because `2018-05-22` = `2018-05-22 00:00:00`

if you want to input only one date, then u can use this

```
 WHERE patients.createdAt >= '2018-05-22 00:00:00'
       AND patients.createdAt <= '2018-05-22 23:59:59'
```

or you can simply use this

```
 WHERE patients.createdAt LIKE '2018-05-22%'
```

it will give you all of the row which has the value '2018-05-22' on it

Comment: hi @18Man      

Those are two different dates, 

I mean what if you only input the same two dates without inputting the time it will produce 00:00:00 - 23:59:59. 

Example: I input patients.created_at> = '2018-05-22' and patients.created_at <'2018-05-22' 

then it will not generate a value because the default time is 00:00:00 - 00:00:00.

How to change the time format so that when we input only two of the same date without the time it will read 00:00:00 - 23:59:59

Answer (score 0):

Try using `...WHERE DATE(patients.created_at) = '2018-05-22'...`

Comment: based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104364/12582712, this query is a performance killer