# Invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function (with union and rollup)

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, union, rollup

i have query like below

```
select COALESCE(Funding_Type, 'Total') as Funding, nama as nama1, sum(total) as Revenue
from (select ('NDIS') as Funding_Type, business_name as nama, sum(total_amount) as total
      from invoices a inner join
           businesses b 
           on a.business_id=b.id and invoice_to like '%NDIS%'
      union ALL
      select ('CHSP') as Funding_Type, business_name as nama, sum(total_amount) as total 
      from invoices a inner join
           businesses b 
           on a.business_id=b.id and invoice_to like '%CHSP%') x
GROUP by ROLLUP (Funding_Type, nama);
```

And get results like this

```
Column 'businesses.business_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either 
an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that your groups are non-overlapping.  I assume this is the case; otherwise, you are double counting revenue which seems like a bad thing.

With this assumption, you can use a single `case` expression for the aggregation:

```
select coalesce(Funding_Type, 'Total') as Funding,
         nama as nama1, sum(total) as Revenue
from (select (case when invoice_to like '%NDIS%' then 'NDIS'
                   when invoice_to like '%CHSP%' then 'CHSP'
              end) as Funding_Type,
             business_name as nama, total_amount as total
      from invoices i inner join
           businesses b 
           on i.business_id = b.id
     ) ib
where funding_type is not null
group by rollup (Funding_Type, nama);
```

Comment: Thankyou bro, can you help me, I have a case about date and time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712954/how-to-read-from-the-two-same-dates-without-input-the-time

Comment: @ryan . . . When you ask a question and it has been answered satisfactorily, you should accept one -- and exactly one -- answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not grouping by `business_name` in the inner queries so you cannot select it without some kind of aggregation. Incidentally, your inner group by is unnecessary, so we can just remove it:

```
select
    COALESCE(Funding_Type, 'Total') as Funding,
    nama as nama1,
    sum(total) as Revenue
from (
    select 'NDIS' as Funding_Type, business_name as nama, total_amount as total
        from invoices a 
        inner join businesses b on a.business_id=b.id
        and invoice_to like '%NDIS%'
    union ALL
    select 'CHSP', business_name, total_amount
        from invoices a 
        inner join businesses b on a.business_id=b.id
        and invoice_to like '%CHSP%'
) x
GROUP by ROLLUP (Funding_Type, nama);
```

You probably want a `COALESCE` on `nama` also, for the subtotal.

---

***EDIT***

If you want to have multiple checks on `invoice_to`, you can simplify the whole query like this:

```sql
select
    COALESCE(Funding_Type, 'Total') as Funding,
    business_name as nama1,
    sum(total) as Revenue
from invoices a 
inner join businesses b on a.business_id=b.id
join (values    -- you could also use a table variable or TVP here
    ('NDIS'),
    ('CHSP')
) v (Funding_Type) on b.invoice_to like '%' + v.Funding_Type + '%'
GROUP by ROLLUP (v.Funding_Type, business_name);
```

Note that you may get doubled up rows if a row matches more than one `Funding_Type`.

Comment: what if we wanted to add a condition
example: and b.business_name = 'Marli and Moe'. Do we have to add it in each inner join or can we put it only once?
and placed where?

`and invoice_to like '%CHSP%'
and b.business_name='Marli and Moe'
) x
GROUP by ROLLUP (Funding_Type, nama);`

Comment: Thankyou bro, can you help me, I have a case about date and time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712954/how-to-read-from-the-two-same-dates-without-input-the-time